# What's the meaning of second sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hypothetically in the context of

> What's your favorite restuarant to eat food?
>
> If they have food, I'll eat it.".

Does the second sentence mean they would eat food at a single resturant or multiple restaurants?

Comment: I would interpret it as 'If they (any restaurant, using the corporate 'they') have food, I'll eat it'. In other words, I am not fussy; I'll happily eat anywhere. Note: it sounds silly and redundant to talk of a 'restaurant to eat food'. That's what you do in a restaurant.

Comment: Can it be interpreted as a single restaurant?

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect. A restaurant does not eat food. And it makes little sense; why go to a restaurant if *not* to have a meal??

Comment: Toulouse, any restaurant means any single restaurant.

Comment: We don't say: A favorite restaurant to eat food. Also, since all restaurants have food by definition, you don't need anything after favorite restaurant....

Comment: We say: What's your favorite restaurant? OR What're your favorite restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

When the person responding says, 'If they have food, I'll eat it', they are saying that it doesn't matter what restaurant they're visiting. If they're in a restaurant, then they will eat the food there. They're ignoring the question about which restaurant is their favorite and implying that they don't have a favorite. They're saying that they like any restaurant because what's important is not that it's a good restaurant, but that there is food there they can eat.

You might be confused by the pronoun, 'they', which is normally a plural pronoun. But in this case it is not referring to multiple restaurants. 'They' means the people running the restaurant where the person is.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sarcastic way of saying "I like all restaurants equally".

The first sentence contains an odd phrasing "... to eat food." Because by definition a restaurant is a place to eat food.

So I suppose the answer is making fun of this by being sarcastic:

> If they have food (sarcastic condition because all restaurants have food)  I'll eat it (I don't care about how good the food is or anything else. So I like all restaurants the same.)